# Why is "/page/2/" not working?

Tags: permalinks, wp-query, pagination

Finally got pagination to work with the below code, but now the pagination links to /videos/page/2/, which doesn't exist. How do I get page 2 to work?

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('post_type=videos&showposts=1'.'&paged='.$paged);

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
  //display stuff
endwhile;           

php  wp_pagenavi();
 ?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend overriding the main query like that, have you considered using `pre_get_posts`? Then you can use the built in pagination code rather than writing your own, and you can simplify down to a standard post loop

Comment: Also, WordPress provides a standard archive page for post types, so you should already have a post archive at `/videos/` that will load `archive-videos.php`, that requires no messing around with queries

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the answer:

> After a looong day debugging thru wordpress core, I managed to solve
>   this issue.
>
> Basicly, you CANT have a PAGE and a CUSTOM POST TYPE with the same
>   name. If you do, the permalink rewrite rules will get confused and
>   trigger a 404.
>
> A very simple solution I'm using is: The page that lists the custom
>   post types is called in plural (eg. products) and the actual post type
>   name is in singular (eg. product). So they dont conflict and it's all
>   fine.
>
> Done Done! Hope this will save people's time.

- via rafaelxy (http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-with-custom-post-type-listing)

Comment: I guess, not just custom post, you can't have a post and a page with the same name as well.

Comment: 9 years passed, still actual! Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what this means... But I know it is the solution!

Comment: This post helped me. Not sure if it's the exact same issue, but renaming my page from search/ to search-2 fixed a similar pagination issue. I assume I have a conflict in my theme on the search/ slug. Can anyone here suggest how to confirm that? Can't find any reference to "search" in wp_posts - post_name.

Answer (score 6):

After a long time I found a solution for this issue (thanks to [franzblog](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-not-working-after-updating-wordpress-44-45?replies=3#post-7996082)).

If you are using version 4.2 or higher, you need to add the following lines in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'custom_disable_redirect_canonical' );
function custom_disable_redirect_canonical( $redirect_url ) {
    if ( is_paged() && is_singular() ) $redirect_url = false; 
    return $redirect_url; 
}
```

Everything is working fine now!

Answer (score 3):

> you CANT have a PAGE and a CUSTOM POST TYPE with the same name

Maybe tree years ago it was impossible, but now you CAN.

First, add this lines to `$args` into your post type:

```
'has_archive' => false,
'rewrite'     => array(
                 'slug'       => 'your slug', // if you need slug
                 'with_front' => false,
                 ),
```

Second, in `functions.php` add action:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    foreach ($wp_post_types as $wp_post_type) {
        if ($wp_post_type->_builtin) continue;
        if (!$wp_post_type->has_archive && isset($wp_post_type->rewrite) && isset($wp_post_type->rewrite['with_front']) && !$wp_post_type->rewrite['with_front']) {
            $slug = (isset($wp_post_type->rewrite['slug']) ? $wp_post_type->rewrite['slug'] : $wp_post_type->name);
            $page = get_page_by_slug($slug);
            if ($page) add_rewrite_rule('^' .$slug .'/page/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=' .$page->ID .'&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
        }
    }
}

function get_page_by_slug($page_slug, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $page = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = %s AND post_type= %s AND post_status = 'publish'", $page_slug, $post_type ) );

    return ($page ? get_post($page, $output) : NULL);
}
```

Don't forget to flush rules in dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that, on the admin dashboard `Settings -> Reading`, if you have selected a `Posts page`, the option `Blog pages show at most` will conflict with your custom `posts_per_page` query in that page.

So make sure that you either unselect the posts page, or make sure the posts per page matches the `Blog pages show at most` option in `Settings -> Reading`.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent so much time trying to figure out what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

After debugging a long time even I got the solution regarding pagination issue

Basically, In WordPress, you can't have a PAGE and a CUSTOM POST TYPE with the same name. If you do, the permalink rewrite rules will get confused and trigger a 404.